# Clear focus after click in item autocomplete

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, focus

I have a problem. If I set clearFocus() in setOnItemClickListener it's not work.
Focus set nearby input.
How I can clear focus in autocomplete, after I clicked item?

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                arrAuto = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.item_auto)).getText();
                findViewById(R.id.editText1).clearFocus(); //it's not work
            }
        });
```

Comment: why dont you set focus to any other view after clicking...?

Comment: I just do not like this solution

Comment: OK, may be anybody knows how clear focus after start app? I want if app started - all inputs don't have focus.

Comment: OK, I now simple hide keyboard, question for focus closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to your activity in **AndroidManifest** in order to keep the keyboard hidden when the activity is started.